# difference between list addition & list append, and list variable scope in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree

I was solving LeetCode problem (link - [click here](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/)). Basically, the problem is to find all paths in given binary tree.

Consider following binary tree.

```
   1
 /   \
2     3
 \
  5
```

My working solution is as follows -

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def binaryTreePaths(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        res = []
        self.dfs(root, [], res)
        a = []
        for path in res:
            a.append('->'.join([str(i) for i in path]))
        return a

    def dfs(self, root, ls, res):
        if root == None:
            return

        ls = ls + [root.val]
        if not root.left and not root.right: # if it is a leaf
            res.append(ls)
        if root.left:
            self.dfs(root.left, ls, res)
        if root.right:
            self.dfs(root.right, ls, res)
```

The code mentioned above works well. but there are subtle points as follows

- If I change `ls = ls + [root.val]` to `ls.append(root.val)` the `res` in function `binaryTreePaths` after calling `dfs` becomes
     `[[],[]]`
- In the same case mentioned above, in function `dfs`, instead of getting `[[1,2,5],[1,3]]`, I am getting `[[1,3],[1,3]]` as final
     value of `res`.

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your implementation -- without the needless class -- :

```
def dfs(root, ls, res):
    if root == None:
        return
    ls = ls + [root.val]
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        res.append(ls)
    if root.left:
        dfs(root.left, ls, res)
    if root.right:
        dfs(root.right, ls, res)
```

Here's the output

```
In [1]: tree = Node(1, Node(2, None, Node(5)), Node(3))

In [2]: res = []

In [3]: dfs(tree, [], res)

In [4]: res
Out[4]: [[1, 2, 5], [1, 3]]
```

Great! It works. Here it is with `.append`:

```
def dfs(root, ls, res):
    if root == None:
        return
    ls.append(root.val)
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        res.append(ls)
    if root.left:
        dfs(root.left, ls, res)
    if root.right:
        dfs(root.right, ls, res)
```

Now, this time however...

```
In [7]: res = []

In [8]: dfs(tree, [], res)

In [9]: res
Out[9]: [[1, 2, 5, 3], [1, 2, 5, 3]]
```

Not so great. Notice, both lists *share* everything... it's almost as if they *were the same list*:

```
In [10]: [hex(id(r)) for r in res]
Out[10]: ['0x104285e88', '0x104285e88']
```

Aha! They *are* the same list!

The reason the first implementation works is because the following line:

```
ls + [root.val]
```

Makes *a new list* (which is why you have to reassign it to `ls`), whereas:

```
ls.append(root.val)
```

**mutates the list in-place**

```
In [20]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x104216288

In [21]: x.append(4)

In [22]: x
Out[22]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [23]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x104216288
```

But look what happens when we use the `+` operator:

```
In [24]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [25]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x1042c8308

In [26]: x = x + [4]

In [27]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x104222588
```

We can use `append` if we copy the list first...

```
In [29]: def dfs(root, ls, res):
    ...:     if root == None:
    ...:         return
    ...:     copy = ls[:]
    ...:     copy.append(root.val)
    ...:     if not root.left and not root.right:
    ...:         res.append(copy)
    ...:     if root.left:
    ...:         dfs(root.left, copy, res)
    ...:     if root.right:
    ...:         dfs(root.right, copy, res)
    ...:

In [30]:

In [30]: res = []

In [31]: dfs(tree, [], res)

In [32]: res
Out[32]: [[1, 2, 5], [1, 3]]
```

And just for the sake of completeness, using the augmented assignment operator, e.g. `some_list += another_list` modifies the list in-place, and is essentially equivalent to `some_list.extend(another_list)`

```
In [38]: x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [39]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x1045e5d08

In [40]: x += [5]

In [41]: x
Out[41]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [42]: print(hex(id(x)))
0x1045e5d08
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, the `ls` is of None type and actually doesn't exists because you are initializing it at that point so it gives an error that `.append` doesn't exists. `ls = ls + [root.val]` is equal to `ls = [root.val]`.  Therefore it works.

Hope this helps! :)